# outputting data using firestore where doesn't work react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want to only render data that was created by a specific user.

To do this, when creating a card, the `author` field was added, which is `equal to user.uid`.

When displaying, I want to use where and display only data `where` the `author is equal to user.uid` of the current user.

But all data is displayed and nothing works

**Menu**

```
function Menu() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState("");
  const [note, setNote] = useState("");
  let [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [warn, setWarn] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const { user } = UserAuth();
  
  const fetchProduct = async () => {
    if (!user) {
      setData([]);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    const ref = collection(db, "langcards-db");
    const q = query(ref, where("author", "==", user.uid));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      q,
      { includeMetadataChanges: true },
      (querySnapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          arr.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
          });
        });
        setData(arr);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    );
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProduct();

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProduct();
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="main-inner">
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={<Layout onSearch={() => onSearchF()} data={data} />}
            >
              <Route index element={<Home data={data} num={data.length} />} />
              <Route
                path="addcard"
                element={
                  <AddCard
                    onChangeWord={onChangeWord}
                    onChangeNote={onChangeNote}
                    onChangeTranslate={onChangeTranslate}
                    onSubmit={onSubmit}
                    word={word}
                    translate={translate}
                    note={note}
                    warn={warn}
                    resetFormAdd={resetFormAdd}
                  />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="saved"
                element={<Saved data={data} setData={setData} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="search"
                element={
                  <Search
                    data={data}
                    ons={onSearchF}
                    filtered={filteredData}
                    searchInput={searchInput}
                  />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="account"
                element={
                  <ProtectedRoute>
                    <Account />
                  </ProtectedRoute>
                }
              />
              <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
              <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
          <div>
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Menu
```

Comment: Updated code as per your error, can you take a look at my answer ?

Comment: I tried and get the same errors and now the data is updated only after refreshing the page

Comment: can you share complete component code as we don't know where this is happening ? Give us minimal code to reproduce the issue so we can emulate what issue you are experiencing

Comment: I added the whole component, if you need something else, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

At first you are trying to get documents using the query method but you are not following the query syntax  and you have to use the `query` keyword. It looks like you are adding a document with an `author` field in the `langcards-db` collection and querying for `name-db` collection.

Here’s how this query should be executed :

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
const ref = collection(db, "name-db");
if(!user) {
  setData([]);
  return;
}
const q = query(ref, where('author','==', user.uid))
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const arr = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    arr.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    });
  });
  setData(arr);
}
```

For more information about [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) go through these docs.

Comment: I tried this code and everything works, cards with `author = user.uid` rendered but i got error in console: `FirebaseError: Function where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined`